# Process - Is it possible to know when I can type a new command again?

Tags: c#

I know how can I spawn a new process to execute as many tasks as I want, however I would like to execute them all in one `bash`/`cmd.exe`.

The problem is, of course that I don't know when it is done since `WaitForExit()` never happens (the bash can run forever).

However maybe it is possible to know when the `StandardInput.WriteLine()` is available so that I know that bash has finished with the task and I can execute next one, or if the last one is finished - close the bash.

Complete Code ([Fiddle](https://repl.it/Hv5p))

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace ProcessExample
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var commands = new List<string> { "dir", "cd C:/", "dir" };
            var startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo
            {
                FileName = "cmd.exe",
                UseShellExecute = false,
                RedirectStandardOutput = true,
                RedirectStandardError = true,
                RedirectStandardInput = true,
                CreateNoWindow = true
            };

            using (var process = Process.Start(startInfo))
            {
                commands.ForEach(command => { process.StandardInput.WriteLine(command); });

                process.BeginOutputReadLine();
                process.BeginErrorReadLine();

                process.ErrorDataReceived   += (object sender, DataReceivedEventArgs e) => { Console.WriteLine(e.Data); };
                process.OutputDataReceived  += (object sender, DataReceivedEventArgs e) => { Console.WriteLine(e.Data); };

                process.WaitForExit(); // This never happends.
            }

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: could you not just have one string for your command, and then exit, then your command is the whole thing you want to process, and just iterate creating command prompts for each one? So like `dir & cd C:/ & dir & exit`

Comment: Nope. I would like to group input and output into seperate buckets so I know which input gave which output. @Dispersia

Comment: I mean, if you have each command prompt for each command, you would definitely know which command gave what output

Comment: Yes @Dispersia But then I cannot chain things like `cd` because every command will be executed in a separate bash. For example - the given example would not work.

Comment: Yes it would, I gave the example: `"dir & cd C:/ & dir & exit"` using & in cmd will daisy chain the commands, so it will run dir, then cd C:/, then another dir, then exit. Do you mean you couldn't preserve the final destination from one chained command to the next?

Comment: @Dispersia But then it would be impossible to know which output is from which command exactly.

Comment: `StandardInput.WriteLine()` is always available. If you attempt to send input before the prompt, it just gets buffered (up to a point, then your process blocks). You have to parse the command output yourself, and detect the prompt for the next command. Note that you'll have to use one of the output mechanisms that _isn't_ line-based. `OutputDataReceived` is only raised at the end of each line of output, so won't be raised for a convention prompt. E.g. `TextReader.ReadAsync()`.

Comment: Note that in your particular example, the only reason that _"this never happens"_ is that the process you started hasn't completed. And it won't unless you tell it to. E.g. add an "exit" to your list of commands.

Comment: Resolving your larger issue makes your question too broad. That is, you need to be examining the output to identify the text shown for a prompt, but this text varies according to your specific scenario, and often in hard-to-detect ways (e.g. the default Windows CLI changes the prompt according to current working directory). You need to constrain this question considerably for it to be a good Stack Overflow question.